# Custom Login Domain for SalesforceSDKManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get my app to to redirect to my custom salesforce URL, instead of the default one.  I can't seem to find a "login domain" option in the SalesforceSDKManager, like there was for the SFUserAuthenticationManager. So, my question is how the heck to do I do this? This is what my set up looks like so far (written in swift)

```
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().connectedAppCallbackUri = CALLBACK_URI
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().connectedAppId = CONSUMER_KEY
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().authScopes = ["web", "api"]
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().launch()
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this (objective-c answers welcome, I'll simply translate them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to solve this.  The key is to set the SFUserAccountManager before launching the SFSDKManager.  Like so:

```
    var sfUserAccountManager = SFUserAccountManager.sharedInstance()
    sfUserAccountManager.loginHost = LOGIN_DOMAIN
    sfUserAccountManager.oauthClientId = CONSUMER_KEY
    sfUserAccountManager.oauthCompletionUrl = CALLBACK_URI
```

Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Another(better) way to do this is to set the [custom login endpoint](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/mobile_sdk/Content/communities_login_endpoint.htm)